# Print Records from FindAll() in CrudRepository

Tags: java, entitymanager, hibernate-entitymanager

I am extending CrudRepository in my Repository class. I want to print the records in my table using the findAll method. So far, I have written a test class, and I can see the result query is correct. How can I print the individual records in the table?

Here is a snippet of my code:
Repository Class

```
public interface RepositoryAda extends CrudRepository{


}
```

Service Class

```
@Service
public class Service{

@Autowired private RepositoryAda repository;

@Transactional
public List selectRecords(){
  return  (List) repository.findAll();
 }

}
```

Test Case:

```
@Test
public void getAllRecords() {
    service.selectRecords();
}
```

How can I print the individual records from the table to a console?

Comment: Also what do you mean print them to a table? Do you just want to print the records to the console in a tabular format? Or do you not know how to traverse an `Iterable`?

Comment: I need to print them to a console.

Answer (score 9):

I prefer to use [Google's Guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) when using the repository interfaces. You can turn `findAll()` `Iterable` into a `List<Type>` with one line.

```
public RecordRepository extends CrudRepository<Record, Long> {}

public class RecordServiceImple implements RecordService {
    RecordRepository recordRepository;

    public List<Record> selectRecord() {
        return Lists.newArrayList(recordRepository.findAll()); // Guava library 
        // or just simply cast it. 
        // return (List<Record>)recordRepository.findAll();
    }
}
```

Then just loop through the list

```
for (Record record : records) {
    System.out.println(record);
}
```

Just overrive the `toString()` in your `Record` class, or whatever your class name is, to tabular formatting using [`String.format()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29)

Comment: Which import is Lists coming from? Based on this line: return Lists.newArrayList(recordRepository.findAll());

Comment: It's from the Guava library. See the link

Comment: Is there another way to do this without using Guava library?

Comment: Yeah, just cast it  `return (List<Record>)recordRepository.findAll();`